Hibernate unidirectional OneToMany cascade insert failed
Have 2 entities:
Module entity with list of properties
@Entity
@Table(name = "module")
public class ModuleEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "module_id", nullable = false)
private List<PropertyEntity> properties; 

//getters/setters etc
}

Property entity with composite ID
@Entity
@IdClass(PropertyEntityId.class)
@Table(name = "module_property")
public class PropertyEntity {

@Id
@Column(name = "module_id")
private Integer moduleId;

@Id
@Column(name = "[key]")
private String key;

@Column(name = "value")
private String value;

//getters/setters etc
}

With corresponding ID
public class PropertyEntityId implements Serializable {

private Integer moduleId;

private String key;

//getters/setters etc
}

Problem is that when I'm trying to insert Module with Properties list JPA tries to insert module_id twice and second value is null in this case

GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement [The value is not set for the parameter number 4.] [insert into module_property (module_id,value,[key],module_id) values (?,?,?,?)]

What's wrong in my mapping?

Do you have a not-null constraint on the module_id column? Remove it - it isn't set or controlled through the PropertyEntity class, so shouldn't be relied upon to not be null. If you want to reliably control it and ensure it isn't null, map it in the propertyEntity as a ManyToOne back to ModuleEntity (so that the OneToMany uses mappedby="module" instead of defining a joincolumn).

@Chris module_id column is a composite ID part, so it cannot be null, as i understand. But you think only one way is to use ManyToOne in PropertyEntity?

If it is null ,how are you setting that basic moduleId Integer property? If you are expecting JPA to set it for you, this isn't the way to do it, and you'll want to setup a reference mapping (look up bidirectional OneToMany/ManyToMany examples, and yes, they can be part of a composite PK). You used to mention a tenant_module_property column but you are not showing it in your edited question anymore, but still show it in an error in a comment to what I consider 'the' answer to this - is it still in your table, and if so, how?

@Chris preparing example for this question I did renaming of tables and properties to simplify example. so name "tenant_module_property" was a typo in this case, because it should be "module_property"

@Chris but the general question was another - is it possible to use in my case unidirectional OneToMany mapping in some way? or only bidirectional?

Using a unidirectional OneToMany has the key not stored within the entity, which just doesn't work for caching or really anything in JPA. Either JPA sets the FK in PropertyEntity using a reference mapping (ManyToOne) that is not null, or you have a basic mapping to the FK that you have to set yourself (So by pulling out the value from ModuleEntity yourself before saving your PropertyEntity  instance).

You need to replace the moduleId property in the PropertyEntity and PropertyEntityId with the module property:
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JsonBackReference
@JoinColumn(name = "module_id")
private ModuleEntity module;

And you should fix the properties field in the ModuleEntity entity:
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "module", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<PropertyEntity> properties;

See example 164 in Hibernate ORM User Guide.
You also need to set a reference to the ModuleEntity instance in each PropertyEntity object that belongs to it. You can do this manually, or use the @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference annotations to have Jackson take care of this for you when deserializing the object.

tried it already, but in result have another error "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'module_id', table 'tenant_module_property'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.". I need to save ModuleEntity together with related properties

@OLA This happens because you don't set a reference to the ModuleEntity instance in each PropertyEntity object.

@JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference can work only for reading data from database? I tried saving data with these annotations - result is the same, error because module_id is null)

@OLA The @Json... annotations work when serializing and deserializing with Jackson. They are useful when your entities are created automatically from a POST request. If you create entities using the new operation, the annotations will not help you. You need to manually set a reference to the parent object in the child object.
